# Installing a cassandra package

Tags: r, cassandra

I'm new to R and cassandra, I'm trying to install the rcassandra package. On the rforge.net site, it says to do:

```
> install.packages('RCassandra',,'http://www.rforge.net/')
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.rforge.net/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘RCassandra’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

Trying a different repository

```
> install.packages('RCassandra',repo='http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/')
Installing package into ‘/home/as/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/
Warning message:
package ‘RCassandra’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

I tried installing from command line, but that does'nt seem to work either:

```
> sudo R CMD INSTALL RCassandra_0.1\-3.tar.gz 
* installing to library ‘/home/as/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
* installing *source* package ‘RCassandra’ ...
** package ‘RCassandra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c cass.c -o cass.o
cass.c:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
make: *** [cass.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RCassandra’
* removing ‘/home/as/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/RCassandra
```

So how do I install the package? I can see the package on the web sites

Comment: That's odd you get an error that the repository could not be reached. I just ran `install.packages('RCassandra',repo='http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/')` from my windows machine and it ran just fine. You could try adding `type="source"` to see if its just a problem of not having executable available. That will allow you to recompile it (assuming you're set up to do such a thing).

Comment: I tried from a mac, still same error. I got it to compile on my mac, since it supports 64 bit. The linux box only supports 32 bit, so not sure how to compile on it.